# I want to take the path dynamically or through cmd in perl script, below is the code

Tags: perl

How can I take path dynamically or through cmd, please help

my $source_dir = "D:/Perl/Source/bin";
my $target_dir = "D:/Perl/Destination/bin";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the user provide the paths on the command line

```
./script.pl D:/Perl/Source/bin D:/Perl/Destination/bin
```

And in your script

```
my $source_dir = $ARGV[0]; my $target_dir = $ARGV[1];
```

You could also use the GetOpt:: modules to do this more elegantly.